# Providing an ExtendedProperty to ReplyAllToItem

Tags: exchangewebservices, php-ews

When replying to an email the send request happens asynchronously which means that the message id is not returned in the response.

[According to Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2010/02/25/determining-the-id-of-a-sent-message-by-using-extended-properties-with-the-ews-managed-api/) the solution is to add an `ExtendedProperty` to the message to act as a unique id which can later be used to find the newly sent email using a `Restriction` in `FindItem`.

I have succeeded in doing this when sending a regular email, as follows:

```
<ns2:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">
    <ns2:SavedItemFolderId>
        <ns1:DistinguishedFolderId Id="sentitems"/>
    </ns2:SavedItemFolderId>
    <ns2:Items>
        <ns1:Message>
            <ns1:ItemClass>IPM.Note</ns1:ItemClass>
            <ns1:Subject>Test create item</ns1:Subject>
            <ns1:Body BodyType="Text">And here is the body</ns1:Body>
            <ns1:ExtendedProperty>
                <ns1:ExtendedFieldURI 
                     PropertyName="CustomId" 
                     PropertySetId="SOME SET ID" 
                     PropertyType="String"
                />
                <ns1:Value>UNIQUE ID</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:ExtendedProperty>
            <ns1:ToRecipients>
                <ns1:Mailbox>
                    <ns1:EmailAddress>my@email.com</ns1:EmailAddress>
                </ns1:Mailbox>
            </ns1:ToRecipients>
        </ns1:Message>
    </ns2:Items>
</ns2:CreateItem>
```

The problem is that when trying to add the `ExtendedProperty` to a `Message` contained in `ReplyAllToItem`, the field is not included in the request.

```
<ns2:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">
    <ns2:SavedItemFolderId>
        <ns1:DistinguishedFolderId Id="sentitems"/>
    </ns2:SavedItemFolderId>
    <ns2:Items>
        <ns1:ReplyAllToItem>
            <ns1:Subject>Subject</ns1:Subject>
            <ns1:ToRecipients>
                <ns1:Mailbox>
                    <ns1:EmailAddress>my@email.com</ns1:EmailAddress>
                </ns1:Mailbox>
            </ns1:ToRecipients>
            <ns1:CcRecipients/>
            <ns1:ReferenceItemId ChangeKey="CQ=" Id="AA="/>
                <ns1:NewBodyContent BodyType="HTML">Body</ns1:NewBodyContent>
            </ns1:ReplyAllToItem>
        </ns2:Items>
    </ns2:CreateItem>
```

By the way I am using php-ews to build the requests.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the underlying types for that operation allow you to add an Extended property. As easy workaround for that is to save the Message first to the drafts folder

```
      <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">
    <m:SavedItemFolderId>
      <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="drafts" />
    </m:SavedItemFolderId>
    <m:Items>
      <t:ReplyAllToItem>
        <t:ReferenceItemId Id="AAMkADczN..." ChangeKey="CQAA..." />
      </t:ReplyAllToItem>
    </m:Items>
  </m:CreateItem>
```

You will then get returned a ItemId to the underlying EmailMessage that gets created by ReplyToAllToItem, you can then just use a normal updateItem request on that email and then send it with the SendItem operation. Its a few more requests but should work okay.